# jQuery get multiple items into array and execute ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements and I need to get the id's of all to pass to an ajax query. Is there a neat way to create a array or list with those elements?

```
<li id="a">...
<li id="b">...
<li id="c">...
```

How do I get something like: items="a,b,c";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
"use strict";

(function () {
  var items = $('li').map(function (index, item) {
    return item.id;
  }).toArray();


  console.log(items);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="a">1</li>
<li id="b">2</li>
<li id="c">3</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution :

```
var optionIds = [];
$.each($("li"),function(i,item) { optionIds.push($(item).attr('id')); });
var str= 'items='+ optionIds .join(',');
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Solution:

```
var idArray = [];
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(e){
    idArray.push(e.id);
});
console.log('items='+idArray.join(','))
```

Note: forEach and querySelectorAll are not supported in older browsers.